# Deploy a Python script and all of its dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, deployment

I have a script that I want to deploy on another computer. My script use module/packages defined in the standard library of Python but also user modules/packages defined in our corporate code base. I would like to make a zip which contains all the files that my script import and which are user modules/packages (the standard python library will be installed on the target computer)

Is there a conventional way to to this in python ?

Script `sample.py`:

```
from helper.DateHelper import DayRangeIterator

def run():
    DayRangeIterator('','') 

run()
```

In the above example I would like to have a zip (a package?) which contains script `sample.py` plus the file(s) in which `DayRangeIterator` is defined

I have tried to play with `setup.py` by doing something like this (see below) but the resulting package (tar.gz) does not contain `helper.DateHelper.*` files

```
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools

setup(
    name='TowelStuff',
    version='0.1dev',
    license='Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike license',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    scripts=['sample.py'], 
    package_dir = {'': 'C:\Codebase\'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html seems to be the right solution